# ImportError in a file that does not exist

Tags: python, django, importerror

when I run `python manage.py runserver`I get the error

```
File "path/to/file/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named project.app.notebook.models
```

even though the file admin.py does not exist and the project that admin.py used to be in does not exist. In fact, the file it finds the ImportError in is not even on the python path.

I use virtualenv and thought it might be that I had activated the wrong virtualenv, but that was not the case.

The error occured after I copied an app from an old project into a new project. I have done this before without problems. Also, I went through and changed all the imports in the app to match the new project.

I've been scanning through the my files and I can't find the import on line 3 in any files.

EDIT: More information

**File structure**

```
project1/
    venv/ # The virtualenv I use
    project1/
        app/
            notebook/
    manage.py # The manage.py I use

# Old project where python finds the ImportError (this project does not exist any longer)
project2/
    venv/
    project2/
        app/
            notebook/
                admin.py # Where python finds the ImportError
    manage.py
```

As mentioned, project2 is deleted from the filesystem and is also outside the python path.
Furthermore I use Django==1.7. If any help, this is my `requirements.txt`

**requirements.txt**

```
Django==1.7
wsgiref==0.1.2
Pillow
sorl-thumbnail
pyjade
django-pagedown
slugify
Beautifulsoup4
django-kronos
-e git://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax@36d45bc0f4380feb69b213241fc6ff74a6d05161#egg=django_ajax-2.2.8
```

Comment: Please include more information in your question, like your project package stucture etc.

Comment: Added more information about the file structure

Comment: try removing *.pyc files and re-run your project.

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed by deleting `.pyc`files in the project as ruddra commented.

Can be done with this comand.

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```